# unit testing with method pointer

Tags: unit-testing

I have a function which takes two file as parameter. It is trying to check directory1, and get path of most recent sub directory, if fail get path of second directory. I want to write a unit test, but not sure how to mock the following part.

```
listFiles(File::isDirectory)
```

pseudo-code of my function

```
try{           
    File[] directories = d1.listFiles(File::isDirectory);
    Arrays.sort(directories, Collections.reverseOrder());       
    return  directories[0].getAbsolutePath();;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return d2.getAbsolutePath()
}
```

Comment: This code deals straight with file system, best test would be test against actual files system, don't mock. You can have dummy directories for different test cases.

Comment: Three questions: 1) You write your code shall return the most recent subdirectory, but you perform a lexicographical sort - what is your real intent?  2) Your code does a catch all - are you aware that there are several reasons why the above code could throw an exception, and is it truly your intent to handle them all alike?  3) Do you already know how to mock getAbsolutePath?